Pulse modulation and PCM
I know the definition of $PCM$ modulation which is described as :

Pulse Code Modulation $(PCM)$ is a digital scheme for transmitting analog data.
It converts an analog signal into digital form

But I found another aspect in Sklar's book :

When Pulse Modulation is applied to binary symbols,  the resulting binary waveform is called a pulse-code-modulation $(PCM)$ waveform.

I would like to understand this second definition and why it is called $PCM$.

This question is similar to: What specifically does PCM refer to?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
